# Given a base class as a parameter, how do I use op<< overload to print the characteristics of a derived class if one is passed?

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism, operator-overloading

This is for a homework assignment.

I have a base class Item and a derived class Book.

I have op<< overloaded in Item class:

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const Item* const item)
{
    out << item->getName() << endl;
    return out;
}
```

As well as in Book class:

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const Book* const b)
{
    out << b->getPages() << endl;
    return out;
}
```

However only the `Item` operator is used when I run my code, and it does not print the pages for a book. I have made sure that a "book" gets printed, not just the base class. From the material I've read it seems that overloading the operators for both the base and derived classes is what you're supposed to do, so I'm not sure why my book info doesn't get printed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use polymorphism instead of overloading: add a virtual print method to the classes:

```
class Item
{
 public:
  virtual void print(std::ostream& o) const
  {
    out << getName() << endl;
  }
 ....
};

class Book : public Item
{
 public:
  virtual void print(std::ostream& o) const
  {
    out << getPages() << endl;
  }
 ....
};
```

then use a single `ostream& operator<<`:

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const Item& item)
{
    item.print(out);
    return out;
}
```

then

```
Item* i1 = new Item(....);
Item* i2 = new Book(....);
std::cout << *i1 << " " << *i2 << std::endl;
delete i1;
delete i2;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you change the derived class function's signature, it's no longer an override of the base class member function.

Comment: So you mean by passing in a Book* instead of a Item* I am no longer overloading? If so, how do I access "book" characteristics to display from the Item* parameter?

Comment: That's correct - overrides (not overloads, my bad) must have identical signature.  The other answer is on the right track.

Comment: @user2152382 What you are trying to do isn't clear enough from your question, but the solution I provided should work fine.

Comment: @SteveTownsend but these shouldn't be overrides anyway, the operator should not be a member function.

Answer (score 0):

"However **only the Item operator** is used when I run my code" - this behaviour might be because you apply it **to the pointer*/reference& on the base class**;

If you have a container in which you want to store instances of different classes what are derived from the same base class and apply to all of them operator<<, which behaviour will depend on the class of instance for each it is invoked, you have to make sure that:

1.There is **at least one virtual method in you base class** (this will cause compiler to generate
**virtual table** for that class and later this table can be used by **operator dynamic_cast**)
2. **Enable RTTI** (run-time type identification) in your project : project/c++/language enable RTTI support
3. **implement operator<<** using the following idea:

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const Item& item)
{
    if (Book* pBook = dynamic_cast<Book*>(&item)
    {
        out << pBook ->getName() << endl;
    }
    if (OtherDerivedClassName* pOtherDerivedClass = dynamic_cast<OtherDerivedClassName*>(&item)
    {
// do other interesting things
    }
    return out;
}
```